# Password policy requirement regex

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords

I need a regex to meet this password policy requirement
Minimum eight (8) characters
At least one number (0-9)
Any three of the following:
Lowercase
Uppercase
Number
Special character (   ! " # $ % & ' ( )
* + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~ )

for now i am using this regex Minimum eight (8) characters

```
/^(?=.*\d)[ !#$%&()*+,.\/:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~\w-]{8,}$/
```

This regex is not working as expected it is taking input of 
testtest1 as a right match.It should take this test@test1,Testtest12 as a right input

Comment: *Any three of the following: Lowercase Uppercase Number Special character* This would be annoyingly repetitive to do in a regular expression. Possible, but consider implementing it programatically instead.

Comment: Looks to me as though you are not escaping characters that have special meaning. Could you also not implement some ASCII character classes?

Comment: But `testtest1` does have a number and `Any three of the following: Lowercase Uppercase Number Special character` right? If you want any of the three, it is going to match https://regex101.com/r/iqgvsm/1 If there should be an uppercase or a special char https://regex101.com/r/sbI8m9/1

Comment: What about using multiple patterns, e.g one that checks for lower case chars, one for upper, one for numbers and one for special... If u apply them all u can easily determine how many criteria match ;)

Comment: @SalmanKhan just for completeness, your regex was aware of spaces... U may want to add them to the other regex too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern will match `testtest1` as you are only asserting a required digit and following character class `[ !#$%&()*+,.\/:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~\w-]{8,}` will repeat matching at least 8 times any of the listed.

---

If you want to assert either an uppercase char A-Z or a special character as well, you could use another positive lookahead with an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*(?:[A-Z]|[!#$%&()*+,.\/:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~-]))[!#$%&()*+,.\/:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~\w-]{8,}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sbI8m9/1)

**Note** that I omitted matching the spaces, you could a space to the character class if you want to match it (Not sure if you would allow spaces in the password)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your lookahead part a bit.

```
^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[0-9].*)(.*[\!"#$%&'\(\)\*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|}~].*){3,}
```

`(?=.{8,})`     = minimum eight characters length (positive lookahead)

`(?=.*[0-9].*)` = at leats one number (positive lookahead)

`(.*[\!"#$%&'\(\)\*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|}~].*){3,}` any character in your list somewhere at least three times

Comment: Please mind that final `.*` inside the positive lookahead is useless. In the finishing capturing group it is even dangerous as it could lead to catastrophic backtracking ([here](https://regex101.com/r/w3U63y/1) already more than 100k iterations to fail)! Besides, it doesn't fulfill the requirements, for "any three of" you forgot lower and upper case characters.